# Google map, autocomplete show state name for select country

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

Is it possible to get only list of states in autocomplete for selected country using google maps.

Currently am getting city,street,state in autocomplete for  selected country,

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
   var map, places, infoWindow;
    var markers = [];
    var autocomplete;
    var countryRestrict = { 'country': 'in' };
    var MARKER_PATH = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker_green';
    var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');

    var countries = {
        'in': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.76, 78.87),
            zoom: 4
        },
        'au': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.3, 133.8),
            zoom: 4
        },
        'br': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-14.2, -51.9),
            zoom: 3
        },
        'ca': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(62, -110.0),
            zoom: 3
        },
        'fr': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.2, 2.2),
            zoom: 5
        },
        'de': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.2, 10.4),
            zoom: 5
        },
        'mx': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.6, -102.5),
            zoom: 4
        },
        'nz': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.9, 174.9),
            zoom: 5
        },
        'it': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9, 12.6),
            zoom: 5
        },
        'za': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.6, 22.9),
            zoom: 5
        },
        'es': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.5, -3.7),
            zoom: 5
        },
        'pt': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.4, -8.2),
            zoom: 6
        },
        'us': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.1, -95.7),
            zoom: 3
        },
        'uk': {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.8, -4.6),
            zoom: 5
        }
    };

    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: countries['us'].zoom,
            center: countries['us'].center,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: document.getElementById('info-content')
        });

        // Create the autocomplete object and associate it with the UI input control.
        // Restrict the search to the default country, and to place type "cities".
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
  {
      //types: ['(cities)'],
      // types: ['(regions)'],
      types: ['(regions)'],
    
      componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
  });
        places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

        // Add a DOM event listener to react when the user selects a country.
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('country'), 'change',
  setAutocompleteCountry);
    }

    // When the user selects a city, get the place details for the city and
    // zoom the map in on the city.
    function onPlaceChanged() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry) {
            map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(15);
            search();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Enter a city';
        }

    }

    // Search for hotels in the selected city, within the viewport of the map.
    function search() {
        var search = {
            bounds: map.getBounds(),
            types: ['lodging']
        };

        places.nearbySearch(search, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                clearResults();
                clearMarkers();
                // Create a marker for each hotel found, and
                // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i);
                    var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';
                    // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
                    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[i].geometry.location,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        icon: markerIcon
                    });
                    // If the user clicks a hotel marker, show the details of that hotel
                    // in an info window.
                    markers[i].placeResult = results[i];
                    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', showInfoWindow);
                    setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
                    addResult(results[i], i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function clearMarkers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (markers[i]) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
        markers = [];
    }

    // Set the country restriction based on user input.
    // Also center and zoom the map on the given country.
    function setAutocompleteCountry() {
        var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
        if (country == 'all') {
            autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions([]);
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(15, 0));
            map.setZoom(2);
        } else {
            autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({ 'country': country });
            map.setCenter(countries[country].center);
            map.setZoom(countries[country].zoom);
        }
        clearResults();
        clearMarkers();
    }

    function dropMarker(i) {
        return function () {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
        };
    }

    function addResult(result, i) {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i);
        var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 == 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
        tr.onclick = function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
        };

        var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
        var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
        var icon = document.createElement('img');
        icon.src = markerIcon;
        icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
        icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
        var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
        iconTd.appendChild(icon);
        nameTd.appendChild(name);
        tr.appendChild(iconTd);
        tr.appendChild(nameTd);
        results.appendChild(tr);
    }

    function clearResults() {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        while (results.childNodes[0]) {
            results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
        }
    }

    // Get the place details for a hotel. Show the information in an info window,
    // anchored on the marker for the hotel that the user selected.
    function showInfoWindow() {
        var marker = this;
        places.getDetails({ reference: marker.placeResult.reference },
  function (place, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          return;
      }
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      buildIWContent(place);
  });
    }

    // Load the place information into the HTML elements used by the info window.
    function buildIWContent(place) {
        document.getElementById('iw-icon').innerHTML = '<img class="hotelIcon" ' +
  'src="' + place.icon + '"/>';
        document.getElementById('iw-url').innerHTML = '<b><a href="' + place.url +
  '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
        document.getElementById('iw-address').textContent = place.vicinity;

        if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
            document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('iw-phone').textContent =
    place.formatted_phone_number;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Assign a five-star rating to the hotel, using a black star ('&#10029;')
        // to indicate the rating the hotel has earned, and a white star ('&#10025;')
        // for the rating points not achieved.
        if (place.rating) {
            var ratingHtml = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
                    ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
                } else {
                    ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
                }
                document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('iw-rating').innerHTML = ratingHtml;
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // The regexp isolates the first part of the URL (domain plus subdomain)
        // to give a short URL for displaying in the info window.
        if (place.website) {
            var fullUrl = place.website;
            var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
            if (website == null) {
                website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
                fullUrl = website;
            }
            document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('iw-website').textContent = website;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. According to [Google Maps API Autocomplete Library Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete),
you can only restrict results up to regions level which in some results it is returned city or even street name.

In `Autocomplete()` function, you have four `types` to expect in results as mentioned in docs and you have already known I think: `geocode`, `establishment`, `(regions)`, `(cities)`.

However, if you can use another autocomplete plugin or built yours and feed it with `autocomplete.getPlace()` object values, it is sure possible.